# How to log all Bash (busybox/ash) commands by all users on a server?

Tags: syslog, busybox

How can we locally log all Bash commands run, along with user and time stamp?

I am looking for a way to customize Ash sessions with my own sets of aliases and whatnots. What is the Ash equivalent of Bash's `bashrc` files?

Standard solution not working:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

- os: linux 4.9
- bash: .ash
- logger: busybox (1.27.2) & syslog-ng (3.10)

Answer (score 0):

This is for rsyslog:

1. Edit /etc/rsyslog.conf and put there a line

   ```
   local6.*                                  /var/log/mylog
   ```
2. Instead of PROMPT_COMMAND export PS1 in /etc/profile for example:

   ```
   export PS1='$(RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "[$$]: $(history | tail -1) [$RETRN_VAL]")\u@\h:\w\$ '
   ```

Of course you can change the command to get rid of unnecessary characters from history output.